# The Bind Value at index 1 is null

Tags: javascript, sqlite, mobile, titanium

I am using the sqlite in my app using titanium and i am using variable in query.The problem with me is that when i don't use variable it gives me the perfect result.The query without variable is as

```
   "select * from IQ where Quote_id =1 "
```

and when i use the variable it gives me the above mentioned error.The query with the variable is as follows and the value of Ti.App.index maybe between 0-47

```
  "select * from IQ where Quote_id =? ",Ti.App.index
```

could somebody help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this syntax

```
"select * from IQ where Quote_id ='"+Ti.App.index+"' "
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Ti.App.index is not null?  This type of error usually means the input value is null.

Would this work:

```
"select * from IQ where Quote_id =? ",new String[] { Ti.App.index }
```

or

```
"select * from IQ where Quote_id = " + Ti.App.index
```

Good luck.